# Mapping an object to self

Tags: c#, automapper

We are currently using v8 of AutoMapper in our code and is planning to upgrade to 9.0+. For that we need to convert all static mappers to instance based.

We have a lot of code in our code base like this below.

```
public class ConfigModel 
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    ...
    
    public ConfigModel Load(ConfigEntity config)
    {
        Mapper.Map(config, this);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am looking for something similar that we can do with `IMapper`. We just need to map an Entity to the properties in the model.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include the question you want to ask. If possible add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using dependency injection. You need somewhere to inject the mapper instance. I recommend a factory.

```
interface IConfigModelFactory
{
    ConfigModel CreateInstance(ConfigEntity config);
}

class ConfigModelFactory : IConfigModelFactory
{
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ConfigModelFactory(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public ConfigModel CreateInstance(ConfigEntity entity)
    {
        return new ConfigModel(_mapper, entity);
    }
}

public class ConfigModel
{
    public ConfigModel(IMapper mapper, ConfigEntity entity)
    {
        mapper.Map(entity, this);
    }
}
```

Now wherever you need to create instances of the `ConfigModel` class, inject your factory, and the mapper will come along with it (assuming you've registered it). Use the factory instead of using `new` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, AutoMapper has a method with a definition like this. I could not find it in the documentation page but this is part of the package.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Execute a mapping from the source object to the existing destination object.
//
// Parameters:
//   source:
//     Source object to map from
//
//   destination:
//     Destination object to map into
//
// Type parameters:
//   TSource:
//     Source type to use
//
//   TDestination:
//     Destination type
//
// Returns:
//     The mapped destination object, same instance as the destination object
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination);
```

So we can do this and in a model, we can map an entity to self.

```
this.mapper.Map(entity, this);
```

This can be unit tested using Moq like this.

```
var mapper = autoMocker.GetMock<IMapper>();
mapper.Setup(a => a.Map<Entity, Model>(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
    .Returns(new Model
    {
        Prop1 = "val 1",
        Prop2 = "val 2",
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that you have a class for ConfigModel and inside is this Load method, something like that:

```
public class ConfigModel{
   int MyProperty1 { get; private set; }

   public ConfigModel Load(ConfigEntity config)
   {
      Mapper.Map(config, this);
      return this;
   }

   public ConfigModel(int myProperty1) // <-constructor
   {
      MyProperty1 = myProperty1;
   }
}
```

So to map object to itself you don't even need a mapper, have a method that maps incoming object to this object:

```
public class ConfigModel{
   int MyProperty1 { get; private set; }

   public ConfigModel Load(ConfigEntity config)
   {
      Map(config);
      return this;
   }

   public void Map(ConfigModel configModel) // <- mapping method without using AutoMapper, using something like that does not collide with other mappings using AutoMapper
   {
      this.MyProperty1 = configModel.MyProperty1
      //... you can map as many properties as you like
   }

   public ConfigModel(int myProperty1) // <-constructor
   {
      MyProperty1 = myProperty1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I copied the class definition from your answer to my question because I thought that will give the question a little more readability.  Sorry for doing that without permission.

Comment: That's fine, no problem